# Pyspark Change String Order

Tags: string, indexing, pyspark

I have a dataframe below;

```
Leadtime
303400
333430
1234111
2356788
258
```

I completed all the strigns in the data to 7 digits.

> filler = udf(lambda x: str(x).zfill(7))
>
> df =df.withColumn('Leadtime',filler('Leadtime'))

Output is;

```
Leadtime
0303400
0333430
1234111
2356788
0000258
```

After that,

I want to write a method that will make the first index of the strings the last index as follows;

```
Leadtime
3034000
3334300
2341111
3567882
0002580
```

Could you please help me about this?

Answer (score 2):

You can select a substring with [substr](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.substr) and concatenate strings with [concat](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.concat):

```py
#string change string
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

l = [('303400',)
,('333430',)
,('1234111',)
,('2356788',)
,('258',)]

df=spark.createDataFrame(l, ['Leadtime'])

filler = F.udf(lambda x: str(x).zfill(7))

df =df.withColumn('Leadtime',filler('Leadtime'))

df.withColumn('Leadtime', F.concat(df.Leadtime.substr(2, 6), df.Leadtime.substr(1, 1))  ).show()
```

Output:

```
+--------+
|Leadtime|
+--------+
| 3034000|
| 3334300|
| 2341111|
| 3567882|
| 0002580|
+--------+
```